# ModelBinding From ViewModel To Domain Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a domain class `Customer` as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsLetter { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MembershipTypeId")]
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

and `MembershipType` class like this:

```
public class MembershipType
{
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a form for customer registration for which I need to provide a dropdown list to select the `MembershipType` so I have created a view model class :

```
public class CustomerAndMembershipTypesViewModels
{
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MembershipType>? MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Now for the view, I have set the above view model as the model behind the page:

```
@model CustomerAndMembershipTypesViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Form";
}

<form asp-action="AddCustomer" asp-controller="Customer" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.MembershipTypeId"></label>
        <select asp-for="Customer.MembershipTypeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes,"Id","Name"))" class="form-control">
            <option>Select MembershipTypes</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.MembershipTypeId"></span>
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.MembershipType"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.BirthDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.BirthDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.BirthDate"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter "/>
        <label asp-for="Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

</form>
```

While posting the form, all the fields that will be posted are related to the customer domain model, so I'm trying to map the post data to `Customer` domain model as shown here:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CustomerAndMembershipTypesViewModels customerAndMembershipTypesViewModels = new CustomerAndMembershipTypesViewModels()
            {
                Customer = customer,
                MembershipTypes = MembershipTypeRepository.GetMembershipTypes()
            };

        return View("CustomerForm", customerAndMembershipTypesViewModels);
    }

    CustomerRepository.CreateCustomer(customer);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

The mapping will work in ASP.NET MVC, but not in ASP.NET Core MVC. I'm getting this error:

[image]

Why is ASP.NET Core MVC not able to identify that only domain model value is posted by the form?

Comment: Read the error message - it has nothing to do with not being able to map the posted fields to the class - the problem is that you have **multiple methods** in your controller that accept the same model class and ASP.NET Core MVC cannot figure out which one to call .....

Comment: @marc_s there is no other method in the controller except the GetMethod and PostMethod as follows:-

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddCustomer()

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddCustomer(Customer customer)

Comment: While I was trying to reproduce your issue, I came to see `CustomerForm` could you please share details? The error is pretty straightforward and it usually encounters when two actions seems similar in reagards of name and parameter within a controller. On top of this, could you please let us know, in which line you are getting the exception? In addition, what's your .NET core version?